# How to remove "Contains Ads" from store listing

Tags: admob

I decided to remove advertising from my Android app, so I removed AdMob-related code and libraries and republished. However, the store listing still shows "Contains Ads". I have not found anywhere in the Google Play Console that allows me to indicate the app does not contain ads. Is there a way to remove that?

Answer (score 11):

I finally found it. In the Google Play Console, go to App Content under Policy in the sidebar. You can change the Contains Ads setting there.

Comment: tx this was driving me crazy.